# C#/LINQ: How to Query this XML Structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get the value of `<getthis>` but can't seem to get just the string value. I think this is quite simple but I can't seem to get it. I am trying to do it with LINQ

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name></name>
        <title></title>
    </item>
    <info>
        <getthis>value here</getthis>
        <something>another value</something>
    </info>
</upload>
```

I used

```
var link = from links in doc.Descendants("getthis")
           select links;
```

but I want just the value. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var link = from links in doc.Descendants("getthis")
           select links.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to get the getthis under info I would use the following:

```
var result = from info in xd.Descendants("info")
             from getthis in xd.Descendants("getthis")
             select getthis.Value;
```

If that's not important Darin's answer is correct.